# Что это за css псевдоэлементы в html? Есть ли полифилл

Tags: javascript, html, css

Наткнулся на безобразие подобное этому:

```
 <div>
 ::after
 <div>content</div>
 </div> 
  или
  <div>
  #main
  <div>content</div>
  </div>
```

Что вообще это такое? Как оно называется?Это В спецификациях ничего не нашел.
Подскажите ссылку если знаете. Поиск в интернете наполобие "псевдоклассы css в html"
Это результат какого-то фреймворка?
Как вообще wc3 допустила подобное в html коде?
Так большинство браузеров не работают с этим.
Есть ли полиффил или браузерный плагин чтобы справиться с этой напастью?
Это быстро распространяется. А спецификаций и полифилла нет.

Мне непонятна прямая вставка между тегами. Это какой-то конструктор?

Я вижу эти элементы чаще всего в системах комментариев 
Там где я вижу эти элементы чаще всего возникают ошибки и ничего не показывается.

Например один из них:
https://github.com/join?source=header-home
Символ
        # document ...

Или случайно наткнулся:
Topwar.ru

```
<div class="loader-dots"><div class="dots"></div></div>
::before
 <div>..</div>
::after
```

Кругом где они есть ничего не работает.

Comment: Почти все браузеры поддерживают псевдо классы https://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aafter

Comment: Я не говорю о псевдоклассах в теге <css> или с атрибутом css.Я спрашиваю о том что эти псевдоклассы вставляет прямо между html тегами  и это только недавно появилось и крашит  браузеры.

Comment: Что именно не понятно? [Псевдоклассы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/cat/pseudoclass) и [псевдоэлементы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/cat/pseudoelement) появились в `css3`

Comment: Мне непонятна прямая вставка между тегами. Это какой-то конструктор?

Comment: А вы где видите эти псевдоэлементы? Случайно не в DevTools?

Comment: Конечно в DevTools. Блоки после этих первоэлементов не нормально работают. То есть вы хотите сказать что эти псевдолементы видны только в devtools и это нормально. Просто только недавно начал замечать их.

Comment: Это псевдо элементы а не псевдо классы

Comment: При верстке html вы их указать не сможете. DevTools вам помогает и показывает эти элементы, что бы вам легче было понять, что происходит. А насчет того, что они все ломают... Хмм... Даже и не знаю, что сказать. Разве что - покажите пример, где псевдоэлементы сломали что-то.

Comment: Что за «один из них» по указанной вами ссылке, непонятно. Кто кого где сломал и о каких ошибках речь, тоже непонятно. Хоть скриншот покажите, что ли

Comment: Псевдоэлементы поддерживаются всеми браузерами ещё со времён Internet Explorer 8 и активно используются каждым современным сайтом, в том числе на Stack Overflow

Comment: «Кругом где они есть ничего не работает.» — ещё раз: псевдоэлементы есть даже на Stack Overflow, но судя по тому, что вы успешно редактируете текст вопроса — он у вас отлично работает? Значит проблема абсолютно точно не в псевдоэлементах. А в чём проблема — непонятно, потому что вы почему-то стесняетесь рассказывать подробности о вашем «ничего не работает»